# WooCommerce Product Subtitle plugin input filed html tag not allowed

Tags: wordpress

I have develop  wordpress website

I have used  wordpress  plugin  'WooCommerce Product Subtitle' to add text under the title.

But the input didn't allow html tags.

I need the input allow html tags to put custom style per the product

How can I make that input allow html tags for customizations plugins?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to override single product template to your custom theme.

```
<?php 
global $post;
$subtitle =  get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'wc_ps_subtitle', true );
echo '<div style="font-size:26px;">'.$subtitle.'</div>';
?>
```

You can get subtitle from above code and manage HTML tag also.

Happy Coding.